# BigQuery subquery to return last month's grouped field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using standard SQL in BigQuery.

I have the following query that groups monthly invoices to present total revenue:

```
SELECT 
SUM(table.revenue) AS total_revenue, 
COUNT(table.name) AS invoice_count, 
DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH) AS reporting_month,

FROM table

WHERE table.site = '123'

GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH)
```

This prints:

| total_revenue | invoice_count | reporting_month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100.00 | 30 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 UTC |
| 50.00 | 25 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 UTC |
| 125.00 | 50 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 UTC |

I am trying to get the percentage difference from last month.

I thought I would start with a subquery to reference the previous month and then take that to compare to the current month.

```
SELECT 
SUM(table.revenue) AS total_revenue, 
COUNT(table.name) AS invoice_count, 
DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH) AS reporting_month,

(SELECT SUM(table.revenue), 
FROM table
WHERE table.site = '123'
) AS previous_month_total_revenue

FROM table

WHERE table.site = '123'

GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(table.date__c, MONTH)
```

'previous_month_total_revenue' is currently printing the total for all time on each row. I thought maybe I could do something like this in my subquery:

```
(SELECT SUM(table.revenue), 
FROM table
WHERE table.site = '123'
AND DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
) AS previous_month_total_revenue
```

However this does not run. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `LAG()` -- assuming you have a row for every month:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH) AS reporting_month,
       SUM(table.revenue) AS total_revenue, 
       COUNT(*) AS invoice_count, 
       LAG(SUM(table.revenue)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(reporting_month)) as total_revenue_prev,
       LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(reporting_month)) as invoice_count_prev
FROM table
WHERE table.site = '123'
GROUP BY reporting_month;
```

If you might be missing months, you can still use window functions, but you need to use `RANGE` and be careful about the time specifier.  A simple method is to count the number of months between two dates:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH) AS reporting_month,
       SUM(table.revenue) AS total_revenue, 
       COUNT(*) AS invoice_count, 
       MAX(SUM(table.revenue)) OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH), DATE('2000-01-01')
                                     RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                                    ) as total_revenue_prev,
       MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH), DATE('2000-01-01')
                           RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                          ) as invoice_count_prev
FROM table
WHERE table.site = '123'
GROUP BY reporting_month;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT 

SUM(t1.revenue) AS total_revenue, 
COUNT(t1.name) AS invoice_count, 
DATE_TRUNC(t1.date, MONTH) AS reporting_month,
t2.previous_month_total_revenue

FROM table t1, 
    (SELECT SUM(table.revenue) AS previous_month_total_revenue 
    FROM table 
    WHERE table.site = '123'
    GROUP BY DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) t2
WHERE t1.site = '123'
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(t1.date__c, MONTH)
```

OR

```
SELECT 

SUM(table.revenue) AS total_revenue, 
COUNT(table.name) AS invoice_count, 
DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH) AS reporting_month,
(SELECT TOP 1 SUM(table.revenue) FROM table WHERE table.site = '123' GROUP BY DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS previous_month_total_revenue

FROM table
WHERE table.site = '123'
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(table.date__c, MONTH)
```